# no persistent classes found for query class: from DOCUMENT where doc_firm_id= 317989

Tags: hibernate

I do not have idea what is the problem with configuration. I always get the same warning information.

Main class

```
public class main {
private static SessionFactory factory;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

   DOCUMENT user = new DOCUMENT();
   System.out.println("DOC_ID= "+ user.getDoc_id());

   Query qry=session.createQuery("from DOCUMENT where doc_firm_id= 317989 ");
    List results = qry.list();

    for (Iterator iterator =
         results.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
        DOCUMENT result= (DOCUMENT) iterator.next();
        System.out.print("First Name: " + result.getDoc_id());

    }

    session.close();
```

CoDMS.hbm.xml -> name of class DOCUMENT TABELA from DATABASE Document

```
   <class name="DOCUMENT" table="DOCUMENT">
        <id name="doc_id" type="int">
            <column name="DOC_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="doc_firm_id" type="int">
            <column name="DOC_FIRM_ID" length="10" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="doc_status" type="string">
            <column name="DOC_STATUS" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="doc_type" type="string">
            <column name="DOC_TYPE" length="30" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="doc_name" type="string">
            <column name="DOC_NAME" length="128" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="doc_upload_date" type="date">
            <column name="DOC_UPLOAD_DATE" length="6" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="doc_content" type="binary">
            <column name="DOC_CONTENT" length="6" not-null="true" />
```

DOCUMENT.JAVA

```
public class DOCUMENT {
    private int doc_id;
    private int doc_firm_id;
    private String doc_status;
    private String doc_type;
    private String doc_name;
    private Date doc_upload_date;
    private byte[] doc_content;
    private String doc_desc;
    private String doc_uploades_system;
    private String doc_uploader_ref;
    private String doc_uploader_name;
    private int doc_removed;
    private String doc_category;
    private String doc_public_id;

    public String getDoc_public_id() {
        return doc_public_id;
    }

    public void setDoc_public_id(String doc_public_id) {
        this.doc_public_id = doc_public_id;
    }

    public String getDoc_category() {
        return doc_category;
    }

    public void setDoc_category(String doc_category) {
        this.doc_category = doc_category;
    }
```

I do not have problem with connection to database only with query select and name of Tabel. I exhausted all idea. Please Give me some guideline

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc*********</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">******</property>
    <property name="connection.password">**********</property>
     <property name="hibernate.default_schema">DMS</property>
      <mapping class="DOCUMENT"/>
      <mapping resource="CoDMS.hbm.xml"/>
      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: could you post the full warning or exception trace......?

Answer (score 0):

```
lis 25, 2016 9:43:27 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.4.Final}
lis 25, 2016 9:43:27 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
lis 25, 2016 9:43:27 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
lis 25, 2016 9:43:28 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
lis 25, 2016 9:43:28 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
lis 25, 2016 9:43:28 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@proxy02-pci.te4.local:7104/co_te4]
lis 25, 2016 9:43:28 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=bzielinski, password=****}
lis 25, 2016 9:43:28 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
lis 25, 2016 9:43:28 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
lis 25, 2016 9:43:28 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
lis 25, 2016 9:43:29 AM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@63070bab
lis 25, 2016 9:43:29 AM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [[B] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@63070bab
lis 25, 2016 9:43:29 AM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [Byte[]] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@2d2ffcb7
lis 25, 2016 9:43:29 AM org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [[Ljava.lang.Byte;] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@2d2ffcb7
DOC_ID= 0
lis 25, 2016 9:43:29 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter concreteQueries
WARN: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from DOCUMENT where doc_firm_id= 317989 
lis 25, 2016 9:43:29 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactor
```